# Blockchain on Container Platforms

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I want to deploy private blockchain with 4 nodes. I am trying to use Kubernetes to create P2P network.I am asked to explore this.I have one question regarding real usage or benefit of Blockchain on Kubernetes. Blockchain is decentralized and distributed system and Kubernetes is built for zero downtime for production deployment and high availability of application.Multiple Pods for application can be build on one single cluster/worker node  which is nothing but one single vm or physical server. These multiple pods can be multiple instances of geth deployment. 
Will this not defeat the purpose of decentralization provide by Blockchain ?

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to use Kubernetes for running private or even public nodes (as long as you expose the RPC ports). Kubernetes manages infrastructure and resource allocation for you; it doesn't make a difference wether you use Kubernetes or not from the perspective of other nodes because they're simple communicating over TCP. You can use Kubernetes to roud robin load balance a cluster of Ethereum nodes that act as a single logical Ethereum node (like Infura).